# I am trying to cerate rest api using core php and want to create login api

Tags: docusignapi, docushare

I am trying to create rest api using core php and want to create login api

using this package "docusign/esign-client": "^6.12"

any suggession thanks in advance !

I am trying to create rest api using core php and want to create login api

using this package "docusign/esign-client": "^6.12"

any suggestions thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Recommend that you go to https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/
Login (you will have to have a developer account) and choose PHP and the right-most package option.
that will download ready-made code using Auth Code Grant that you can use right away to do what you asked.